# A mutable MediaPlayer class that extends or uses android's MediaPlayer class

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I've been developing a cool game for android recently (http://www.androidzoom.com/android_games/cards_and_casino/the-best-card-game-everyaniv_jrbe_download.html) and I've been getting requests for a mute button.
So I've implemented all the required UI stuff and I'm using the application's sharedPreferences to store the isMuted state, but now I need that functionality in the mediaplayer class.
I've thought about extending it, but since the original mediaplayer has the static create method, overriding it might not be a great solution, the same goes for creating a class that holds a mediaplayer instance and creating my own create method - it's doable but it's dirty.
I'm sure I'm not the first person to encounter this issue, can somebody please share their experience on the matter?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

for this can you not use mediaplayer.setvolume()